# Android app doesn't load in Visual studio 2015 with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015

In **Visual Studio 2015** with installed **Xamarin** I create default app: Mobile apps -> Blank app (Xamarin.Forms portable). I run it with default Emulator "**VS Emulator 5'' KitKat 4.4 XXHDPI Phone**" by clicking this button.

Emulator load perfectly and fast but application doesn't load and Visual Studio **Start Debug** button became disable. I can't do anything but close emulator. Then I can click **Start Debug** again. In progressbar in bottom of Visual Studio it's written: "Starting emulator ...".

Creating custom emulator take too long time (more than 30 min). May be I need other settings (but I tried different options).

May be it somehow connected with localization (Russian)? Some folders doesn't able to locate Xamarin project (only Xamarin) in default directory.

Comment: Same problem, blank app doesn't even work out of the box.